# Não sei qual é o problema no meu programa

Tags: c

No exercício eu preciso criar uma struct para o cadastro de uma agenda de endereços, nomes, idade e telefones de cinco pessoas, e definir a estrutura de registro apropriada, o diagrama de blocos e as codificações de um programa que efetuem as seguintes tarefas:

a- o cadastramento das informações: nome, endereço, idade e telefone.

b- a pesquisa da idade.

c- a classificação por ordem alfabética

d- a alteração de algum registro que tenha sido fornecido com erro.

e- sair

O programa deverá ter um menu de opções, para que o usuário selecione a opção desejada independentemente de uma ordem específica.

Segue abaixo o meu programa

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

int i, pesq[90], flag, b[90], j, op, re;
char resp='s';

struct cad_agenda
{
int tel, id;
char nome[90], ende[130];
};
struct cad_agenda a[5];

```
 while(resp=='s' || resp=='S'){
 
 printf("\nPROGRAMA AGENDA\n");
 printf("1-Cadastro e registros\n");
 printf("2-Pesquisa de resgistros\n");
 printf("3-Classificação alfabética\n");
 printf("4-Alteração de registro\n");
 printf("5-Sair\n");
 
 printf("Escolha uma opcao:");
 scanf("%d", &op);  
 printf("\n");
 
 switch(op){
 
 case 1: 
 
 for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
  printf("Digite o nome:\n");
 fgets(a[i].nome,90,stdin);
 
 printf("Digite o endereço:\n");
 fgets(a[i].ende,130,stdin);
 
 printf("Digite a idade:\n");
 scanf("%d", &a[i].id);
 
 printf("Digite o telefone:\n");
 scanf("%d", &a[i].tel);        
 }break;

 case 2: 
 printf("Digite a idade para pesquisar:");
 scanf("%d", &a[i].id);
 
 i=0;
 flag=0;
 
 while(i<=4 && flag==0){
 
 if(strcmp(a[i].id, pesq)==0)
 flag=1;
 
 else
 i+=1;
 }
 
 if(flag==1){
 printf("A idade foi localizada na posicao: %d\n", i);
 else
 printf("A idade não foi localizada!\n");   
 }
 }
 case 3:
 for(i=0; i<=3; i++){
 for(b=i+1; b<=4; b=b+1){
    
 if(strcmp(a[i].nome, a[b].nome)>0){
 
 strcpy(j, a[i].nome);
 strcpy(a[i].nome, a[b].nome);
 strcpy(a[b].nome, j);  
 }  
 }  
 for(i=0; i<=4; i=i+1)
 puts(a[i].nome);
 }break;

 case 4:
 printf("Digite o campo que deseja alterar:");
 fgets(pesq,5,stdin);
 
 i=0;
 flag=0;
 
 while(i<=4; && flag==0){
 
 if(strcmp(a[i].nome, pesq)==0)
 flag=1;
 
 else
 i+=1;  
 }
 
 if(flag==1){
 printf("O nome foi localizado na posicao: %d\n",i);    
 
 printf("2-Nome\n");
 printf("3-Idade\n");
 printf("4-Endereco\n");
 printf("5-Sair\n");
 
 printf("Escolha uma opcao:");
 scanf("%d", &re);
 
 switch(re){
    
 case 2: 
 printf("Digite o novo telefone: %d\n");
 scanf("%d", &a[i].nome);
 printf("O nome foi alterado!"); break;
 
 case 3:
 printf("Digite a nova idade: %d\n");
 scanf("%d", &a[i].id);
 printf("O nome foi alterado!"); break;
 
 case 4:
 printf("Digite o novo endereço!");
 scanf("%d", &a[i].ende);
 printf("O novo endereco foi alterado!"); break
 
 case 5:
 printf("Deseja continuar? [S]IM/ [N]AO + <enter>");
 fflush(stdin); resp=getchar(); 
    
 default:
 printf("Campo nao encontrado!"); break
 }
}
```

}
getch();
return 0;
}

Comment: O código está bem complexo e difícil de entender, além de alguns problemas que o impedem de ser compilado. Tente organizá-lo em funções, isso ajuda muito. Além disso, estruturas devem ser declaradas fora do **main**.

Answer (score 1):

while(resp=='s' || resp=='S'){

sua condição esta errada. o while e uma estrutura de repetição nesse caso ele ira repetir infinita vezes

como descrito nele ate o resp ser diferente de s